# ECONNREFUSED when I try to connect to a websocket client

Tags: python, node.js, express, websocket, socket.io

So I am trying to make a website that converts mp4 to mp3. I have a server and multiple clients. The thing is that my server code will select random client from connected ones, send the file and wait for it to come back. But somehow I could not manage to make it work.

My current code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const net = require('net');
const multer = require('multer');
const io = new Server(http);

const PORT = 80;

app.use(express.static('html'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('myFile'), (req, res) => {
    const file = req.file;
    if(!file){
        res.status(404)
        res.send('File not found.')
        return
    }
    const client = getRandomClient();
    if(!client){
        res.send('No clients are currently connected.')
        return
    }
    console.log(client.port);
    console.log(client.host);
    const stream = net.createConnection({ port: client.port, host: '127.0.0.1', timeout: 60 }, () => {
        //stream.write(file.buffer);
        stream.write("test");
        stream.end();
        res.send('File uploaded.');
    });
    
    stream.on('error', (err) => {
        console.error(`Connection error: ${err}`);
        res.send(err);
    });
});

http.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`Socket connected: ${socket.id}`);
    const address = socket.request.connection.remoteAddress;
    console.log(address);
    const port = socket.request.connection._peername.port
    clients.push({ host: address, port });
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`Socket disconnected: ${socket.id}`);
    clients = clients.filter((client) => client.host !== address && client.port !== port);
    });
    socket.on('file', (data) => {
        console.log("got file");
    });
});

function getRandomClient() {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * clients.length);
    return clients[index];
}

let clients = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code accepts incoming socket.io connections and then pushes those into the `clients` data structure.

Then, later when it gets a `/upload` request, it takes the IP/port from the socket.io connection and tries to create a plain TCP connection to that.  You just can't do that.  Your clients are not listening for incoming connections (they are clients, not servers).  And, even if they already were, that port is already in use by the socket.io connection.

You can instead, save the socket.io connection and send data to that client through the existing socket.io connection (that's what it is there for).

You will, of course, have to keep track of when existing socket.io connections disconnect and remove them from your client's structure also so you don't retain dead connections.